# kgdb refused to be able to access symbols for just one certain driver, nor do those symbols appear in vmlinux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to debug a driver.

gdb says...
(gdb) break i2c-hid.c:i2c_hid_suspend
No source file named i2c-hid.c.
Breakpoint 9 (i2c-hid.c:i2c_hid_suspend) pending.

nm vmlinux ---  does not find any function names from within that file.

cat /proc/kallsyms  ---  shows all the functions names contained in that file.

I added this to the Makefile "EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DI2C-HID_DEBUG -g" to no avail.

Does anyone know what I need to do to make gdb able to see the symbols from this file?

I get symbol level debugging for plenty of other drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like i2c-hid.c is not part of vmlinux, which means it is outside of basic kernel. That is why nm vmlinux does not show symbols related to this file.

cat /proc/kallsyms will show those symbols because it shows all the kernel symbols inclunding drivers' symbols which are not part of vmlinux.

I am not sure whether you are using gdb or kgdb, but I think to debug drivers, you need to use kgdb, not gdb.

If you are already using kgdb, then use add-symbol-file command under it. It will help you load symbols which are outside vmlinux. Simple google search will give you lot of information of add-symbol-file.

Comment: OK I guess this is a good write-up on how to use add-symbol-files. http://freebsd.unixtech.be/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-kld.html.  Thx

Comment: BTW perhaps the best wording for "not part of vmlinux" is "it is a loadable module", correct.  I.e. I could just recompile the kernel with this module built-in and then its symbols would be part of vmlinux, correct?

Comment: Yes, I have not tried it myself, but yes, theoretically by building module built-in, your problem could be solved.

Comment: No doubt you gave the correct answer, but my system seems to be missing yet something else.  I cannot get the resolved addresses as I should be able to.  I've tried this:

kldstat          --  says it's not found.
cat /proc/kallsyms | grep i2c_hid --   shows all 0000000000s next to each symbol.
cat /sys/module/i2c_hid/sections/.text --  is just a   0x0000000000000000

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When debugging Linux kernel, GDB does not automatically load symbols for kernel modules like it would do for user-mode shared libraries. Instead you need to load them manually using the following command:

```
add-symbol-file <kernel module>.o <core address> -s <sectionX> <addressX> -s <...>
```

You can find out the core address of the module (and the addresses of all sections) by setting a breakpoint in the `do_init_module()` function and examining the `mod` variable once the breakpoint is hit:

```
print mod->name
print mod->module_core
print *mod->sect_attrs->attrs@mod->sect_attrs->nsections
```

You can read more about loading kernel module symbols in the [Linux kernel symbol overview](http://visualkernel.com/documentation/kernelsymbols).